# Existe limite máximo de tamanho para uma página HTML?

Tags: html, http, navegador-de-internet

> Obs.: Esta pergunta **não é** sobre otimização de código.

É sabido que os navegadores possuem um limite de tamanho para uma URI. Existe algum tipo de limite para requisição/renderização de um arquivo HTML?

Dando um exemplo simples, digamos que uma página HTML gerada no servidor, por algum bug ou erro de consulta, retorne uma tabela com milhões de linhas e várias colunas. Tal página (com centenas ou milhares de Megabytes) teria sua renderização bloqueada pelo navegador, ou ela é unicamente dependente do número de recursos do hardware em que o navegador está rodando?

Comment: um dos dois lados travará.. ou o server ou o cliente.. Um server um pouco mais carregado, com certeza vai dar algum problema. Mas normalmente o cliente vai dar crash tb. Os browsers normalmente travam depois de uns 60 ou 80mb, mas normalmente o cliente já trava bem antes disso.

Answer (score 3):

Não existe limite no padrão HTML para o tamanho máximo que ele pode ter. Não faria sentido limitar o que um navegador pode aguentar até porque, se o navegador conseguisse passar desse limite, pode ter certeza não seria um padrão que o faria se recusar a aceitar a página.

Basta olhar o quanto os navegadores são compreensivos com HTMLs que possuem erros. Se um navegador se recusar a abrir a página que possui um erro e outro navegador aceitá-la (mesmo que não seja uma exibição perfeita), ele perde um usuário. O mesmo valeria aqui.

Em geral, padrões se limitam a exigir um mínimo de funcionalidade e não a ditar um máximo.

Answer (score 2):

Limites impostos por padrão não, porém **limites existem**, sejam eles do lado do servidor ou do cliente.

Você pode usar um laço de repetição pra gerar algo muito grande e complexo para o navegador renderizar, além de sobrecarregar o seu servidor, que também poderá travar, irá chegar até um ponto no qual o navegador não vai conseguir renderizar de forma satisfatória e irá travar, seja por processamento ou uso de memória, lembre-se que computadores não tem memória infinita, por mais que possuam memória de sobra hoje em dia.

É como uma página de scroll infinito. Irá perceber que a cada scroll fica mais pesado, pode demorar um pouco de acordo com sua máquina, e se quiser ver resultados nítidos carregue uma imagem a cada scroll.

> Por algum bug ou erro de consulta, retorne uma tabela com milhões de
>   linhas e várias colunas.

A maioria dos programadores trata esse erro para que isso não aconteça, na maior parte das vezes se trata de erro de lógica, que pode ser corrigido ou detectado simplesmente fazendo testes.

Enquanto a consulta retorna resultados infinitamente, eles não serão exibidos, somente apenas terminar a execução e imprimir o resultado (ou se você fizer algo dinâmico pra exibir enquanto faz as queries). Em PHP por exemplo, você pode limitar o tempo de execução de um script, caso entre em loop infinito, isso iria parar a execução.

- [Limitar o tempo de execução de um script PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php)

Na maior parte, quando um loop infinito ocorre e você não tem nenhum tratamento pra evitar isso, o cliente recebe um erro 500.

Enquanto do lado do cliente, quando o servidor (numa situação muito improvável) consegue executar e retornar algo absurdo, costumam travar em média de 90 MB, alguns ainda conseguem exibir, porém demoram bastante no processamento.